# Jinja не признаёт одинаковость переменных

Tags: python, django, jinja2

У меня на сайте есть 2 списка(подразделы и разделы) я перебираю разделы и подразделы, если подраздел должен находиться в разделе, то вывожу этот подраздел, но ничего не выводится, хотя названия одинаковы.

```
{% for el in chapt %}
  <input type="checkbox" id="" name="" value="">
  <label for={{ el.root_chap_name }} class={{ el.root_chap_name }}1 id="header1">{{ el.chap_name }}</label>
  <ul id="header1_list" сlass="">
    {% for i in subsections %}
      {% if string(i.root_chap_name) == string(el.chap_name) %}
          <li><a href="">{{ i.subsec_name }} </a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="">{{ i.root_chap_name }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="">{{ el.chap_name }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Знаю ответ, но не могу ответить так как https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba?cb=1

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, всё исправил

Comment: Без данных ничего сказать нельзя. Перепишите код на чистый Питон и посмотрите его работу в отладчике. Скорее всего есть какие-то тонкости в данных. Подозрительный момент - вызовы `string(...)`. Что-то не так с их аргументами если они нужны.